# Getting index of an array's element based on its properties

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have a JavaScript array of objects like this:

```
var myArray = [{...}, {...}, {...}];
```

Each object has unique `id` among other properties:

```
{ 
  id: 4,
  property1: 'something',
  property2: 'something'
}
```

How can I get an index of a particular object in that array, if I only know its `id` property? So if I know that `myArray[x].id == 4`, how can I find `x`?

Comment: ES6 Array.findIndex - see full example below

Answer (score 66, accepted):

```
var index = myArray.map(function(el) {
  return el.id;
}).indexOf(4);
```

For IE below version 9, [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) need a patch, or just use a loop.

Comment: this looks the best, nice. didn't even think of it

Comment: Map should return an array though so this although working, confuses me.For each non matched index of shouldn't there be an element of -1 in the new returned array from map?

Answer (score 21):

Or with ES6 syntax:

```
let index = myArray.map( el => el.id ).indexOf(4)
```

or

```
let index = myArray.findIndex( el => el.id === 4 )
```

Answer (score 7):

Why not simply make a loop ?

```
function indexOfId(array, id) {
    for (var i=0; i<array.length; i++) {
       if (array[i].id==id) return i;
    }
    return -1;
}
```

The fact that there are many facilities in js (or js libraries) doesn't mean you must not, sometimes, write a loop. That's fast and simple.

Comment: Maybe you should use something other than `indexOf`

Comment: This is likely to cause problems elsewhere in his code; perhaps `indexOfId()` or something instead?

Comment: @Nile: No, `indexOf` does not work in here - you'd need `filter`

Comment: @Bergi his original answer consisted of the function name `indexOf` instead of `indexOfId`

Answer (score 3):

[ES6 Array.findIndex](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex)

```
const myArray = [{id:1}, {id:2}, {id3}];
const foundIndex = myArray.findIndex((el) => (el.id === 3));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.reduce()`, which lets you reduce an Array down to a single value.

```
var obj_idx = myArray.reduce(function(idx, item, i) {
  return item.id === 4 ? i : idx;
}, -1);
```

The `-1` is a default value if no match is found.

---

If you have multiple uses for this, you may want to make a function factory.

```
function idxForID(target) {
    return function(idx, item, i) {
      return item.id === target ? i : idx;
    };
}
```

And then use it like this.

```
var obj_idx = myArray.reduce(idxForID(4), -1);
```

Answer (score 0):

If each id is unique, you can do it like this:

```
o1 = {id:1}
o2 = {id:2}
o3 = {id:3}
o4 = {id:4}
a = [o1,o2,o3,o4]
a.indexOf( a.filter( function(i){return i.id==4} )[0] );
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also try a recursive function, though @xdazz's looks rather attractive.

```
var indexOfId = function(arr, id, index) {
    if (!index) { index = 0; }
    if (arr[index].id == id) {
      return index;
    }
    return ((index += 1) >= arr.length) ? -1 : indexOfId(arr, id, index);
};
```