# get the name of an object with certain properties

Tags: javascript, search, object

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Getting index of an array’s element based on it’s properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12553274/getting-index-of-an-arrays-element-based-on-its-properties)

I'm working on creating an address book with HTML, jQuery, JS, CSS, all the normal stuff. It's just a simple C.R.U.D. app, nothing fancy. I'm at an intermediate level and having a little bit of trouble with the method in which I'm going about creating it. I'm making each person in the book be an object. Each object is created with a name such as `obj0`. Then that object would be assigned values such as:

```
obj0.name = "Billy";
obj0.num = "1-207-233-8846";
obj0.address = "18 Phillmore Rd, Miami, Florida";
```

If any of those properties wouldn't work then disregard it, I just made them up for the purpose of an example.

Now I'm realizing that I will most likely need to find which object has the name `"Billy"`. I don't want to make the user have to enter in `obj0` to find Billy.

I'm naming the object `obj0` rather than `Billy` because I want to make it possible to have more than one Billy in the address book.

Okay,now for the actual question:
**How would I get the name or id** (I want to get `obj0` in case that's unclear) **of the object that has the name property of** `"Billy"`.

Assume that I have more than one object. The others would be called `obj1` and `obj2`.

If possible I would also like to be able to search for the object with the number of `"1-207-233-8446"` or other phone numbers/addresses.

Comment: Typically data such as that would be stored in a database where you would query for the information you needed.

Comment: This is a very frequent question. Please have a look at the links on the right.

Comment: @dystroy, Do you know which question is the duplicate?  Most of the "Related" questions seem kind of similar (or totally unrelated) but I can't find one that answers this question.

Comment: @SamuelEdwinWard The problem is that the question is too fuzzy (or more than one question). But any one searching into arrays with property should be good.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why do you call the objects anything at all? obj0, obj1, etc...

Consider (unless you're satisfied with the links to the right, which probably already answers this):

```
function Person( name, num, address ) {
    this.name = name;
    this.num = num;
    this.address = address;
}
```

then you create an array of such objects:

```
var persons = [
    new Person( "Billy", "1-207-233-8846", "18 Phillmore Rd, Miami, Florida" ),
    new Person( "Bob", "2", "somewhere" )
];
```

and searching it becomes easy:

```
for ( var i = 0; i < persons.length; ++i ) {
    if ( persons[ i ].name == "Billy" ) {
        // Found, do something with Billy
        break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

use list to store your all objects and iterate the list and check if the condition of search is satisfied or not, in your case it is "billy".
If you don't want to use list, use an array of object and then iterate with for loop instead.
Hope this has helped. Do tell if you want code for this.

Answer (score 0):

If you put your objects in an array (which I think is a much better choice than giving them all names), you can use the [`filter` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) to get a new array of items matching a criterion:

```
var bobs = addresses.filter(function(address) { return address.name === "Bob"; });
```

Note that `filter` returns an array.  But if you think about it, this is correct, because you could easily have more than one Bob in your address book!

Something neat about this is you can write functions that return the functions to pass to `filter`:

```
function withName(name) {
  return function(address) {
    return address.name === name;
  };
}

function withNumber(number) {
  return function(address) {
    return address.number === number;
  }
}

var bobs = addresses.filter(withName("Bob"));
```

And then, you can write functions that combine those functions to create more specific queries:

```
function and(p1, p2) {
  return function(address) {
    return p1(address) && p2(address);
  }
}

var billy = addresses.filter(and(withName("Billy"), withNumber("1-207-233-8846")))[0];
```