# Retrieving a specific element in my javascript array

Tags: javascript

I have the following javascript array:

```
var vat = [
{ id: '', description: '' },
{ id: 'Zero', description: '0%' },
{ id: 'Six', description: '6%' },
{ id: 'Nineteen', description: '19%' },
{ id: 'TwentyOne', description: '21%' }];
```

I need to get the `description` of the element with `id` of **'Six'**. I think it is possible but I did not succeed.

Any help is welcome.

Thanks.

Comment: I'm assuming you want something other than a for loop?

Comment: Yes Richard, if possible in 1 line.

Comment: Similar questions: http://stackoverflow.com/q/16339635/218196, http://stackoverflow.com/q/12553274/218196.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could `filter` the array to leave only the item you are looking for:

```
var desc = vat.filter(function (item) {
    return item.id === "Six";
})[0].description;
```

Note that [`Array.prototype.filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) is an ES5 method and is not supported by older browsers. You can find a polyfill for it in the MDN article linked to previously.

Comment: This is of course a valid solution, but I might suggest that if possible, turning 'vat' into an object instead of an array using the ids as the property names.

Answer (score 0):

If you know that it is the third item then:

```
vat[2]['description']
```

otherwise you could use filter as suggested by James Allardice

Comment: It's an array of object, so the description is accessed by . not []

Comment: @mArm.ch, using brackets is perfectly valid. Look up javascript bracket notation.

Comment: It would be necessary as well, if the key (the attribute) contained spaces.

Answer (score 0):

The structure of your array makes this a bit more complicated than necessary. Here's an alternative structure for which it's much simpler:

```
var vat = { '': '', 'Zero': '0%' } // and so on
vat['Zero'] // gives '0%'
```

In case you're stuck with the structure you've got, you'll need a loop. For example:

```
var result;
for (var i = 0; i < vat.length; i++) {
  if (vat[i].id == 'Six') {
    result = vat[i].description;
    break;
  }
}
```

PS. the `filter` method suggested in a different answer makes this easier, but it requires a browser that supports at least JavaScript 1.6.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to directly access it, you have to know the position.
Example :

```
var myDesc = vat[2].description;
```

Or you can loop on it.
Example :

```
var myDesc = null
for (i in vat) {
    if (vat[i].id == 'Six')  {
        myDesc = vat[i].desc;
    }
}
```

Hope it's what you needed.

Answer (score 0):

```
    for(var i=0;i < vat.length;i++){
        if(vat[i].id == "Six"){
            alert(vat[i].description);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Could you explain your answer please?

Comment: I added a piece of code that extracts in the `vat[i].description` the `description` of the element with `id` of 'Six'.